# How to populate select/combo box without submitting the master form (ASP)

Tags: html, mysql, forms, asp-classic

I've got a master form on my page, and I want to create onClick events for some of my drop down boxes to populate other drop down boxes depending on the choice made.

I know I can't have a form within a form.

Any advice on how I can achieve this.

I'm using HTML, Classic ASP and Mysql to populate the combo boxes.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John. To do this, you would need an AJAX engine running alongside your Javascript, unless you want your page to reload everytime you want the combos to be populated. 
There are many ways to do this and each easier than the latter, but all of them will require an ASP file doing the response in a XML file.
Start with the basics: Learn about Javascript & Ajax... or cut half of your work/time and learn jQuery's. Trust me,... it's worth the trouble.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/